# JPA changes on DB not written before method finished

Tags: java, jpa, jakarta-ee, java-ee-7

I have a `@Stateless`-Bean which performs some Database operations in a single method

```
public void doOperation(){
    User u1 = createNewUser()
    User u2 = createNewUser()
    User updated = mergeUser(u1,u2) // just as an example
    // should write to database now! 
    otherBlockingOperation()
}
```

However the changes are not visible in the database until the blocking operation finished and therefore not visible in the frontend.

I thought this is because the transaction is not committed until `otherBlockingOperation()` is finished. I then wrapped `otherBlockingOperation()` in a Thread, which did not work again.

However I think the real problem is `merge` which will only update the entity after the method is done. How can I change the values of Object instantly?

Edit:

```
@PersistanceContext
private EntityManager em;
mergeUser(T entity){
    em.merge(entity);
    em.flush();
}
```

Comment: Please provide the code of `mergeUser`, this could be relevant. You are correct on your observation about transactions: In a `@Stateless` bean, a transaction is started (by default) and DB is updated only after transaction is committed. Even if you `entityManager.flush()` during the transaction, DB will be  updated but still changes will be visible in your transaction only (unless some non-standard isolation level is used)

Comment: Also, managing your own threads in a JavaEE app is major no-no. The application server should be the only responsible for thread handling, using JavaEE methodology (i.e. `@Asynchronous` business methods etc)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Depending on the actual business requirements, a possible solution would be to move the `otherBlockingOperation()` method to a new `@Stateless` bean and mark the method as `@Asynchronous @TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.REQUIRES_NEW)`. This will effectively run the method in a new thread and new transaction. You would simply `@Inject` the new bean and call the `otherBlockingOperation()` method.

A new transaction might (or *might not*) be a valid option, depending on business needs (i.e. the new transaction might fail, while the original transaction might succeed). However, the update will be committed in DB sooner (but still after the original transaction is committed) without dependency on the `otherBlockingOperation()` process (or even successful commit).